# No response from ajax json request using curl

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, curl

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="st_epic">
                               <label> EPIC Number</label>
 <input type="text" id="epic_num" name="epic_num">
          <label>Select State</label>
   <input type="text" id="epic_state" name="epic_state"> 
  <button type="submit" tabindex="3" id="sub_epic">Search</button>
                            </form>
     
<script> 
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){

      $('#st_epic').submit(function(){
       var epic_no = $("#epic_num").val();
       var state = $("#epic_state").val();
 
   $.ajax({
         url: '/a1.php',
      method: 'POST',
        data: {epic_no:epic_no, state:state},
    dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function (response){
                if (response.message == 'succes') {
                 console.log("complte =" + response.data);
   var div = document.getElementById('epic_result');
       div.html(response.data);
                     }
                  });
            return false;
    })
})
</script>

<div id="epic_result">
</div>

//a1.php file is 

<?php

     $en = ($_POST['epic_no']);
     $es = ($_POST['state']);
      
    $fields = array(
    'epic_no' => $en,
    'page_no' => 1,
    'results_per_page' => 10,
    'reureureired' => 'a32412c7-5598-401f-903c-f68a8690d4b1',
    'search_type' => 'epic',
    'state' => $es,
    );
 
    $url = 'http://example.in/Search';
    $fields_string = json_encode($fields);
       $ch = curl_init();
      
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: */*'));
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
       $output = curl_exec($ch);
   
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
         {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);                  }
            else
         {
        $out = json_decode($output, true);
        print_r($out);
    //    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
          }
   curl_close($ch);          
?>
```

I am making ajax cross domain request to another domain **example.in**. I have used curl in my php file named as a1.php and also shown below. when i execute this code in my localhost server it doesn't showing any error nor any response. I get json formatted response from **example.in**, but in this request i am not getting it. When i use `echo 'Operation completed without any errors';` in php rather than formatting the output, it displays **Operation completed without any errors**. I am not getting whats going wrong? If any one can help, i will be very thankful. Finding the solution since yesterday still not got, finally asked.

Comment: hi, try to use PHP alone and check wether you get desired output or not.

Comment: what is the reason to use `json_decode` here? u can simply use `echo $output;` here

Comment: even though $output doesn't display output @devpro

Comment: chk curl errors

Comment: Thanks bro it has worked @devpro

Comment: what u tried ? plz share

Comment: i have simply displayed the output using `print_r($output);`

Comment: but how can u get the data in json? maybe it just be echo

Comment: in my script there is one more input which is captcha. Right now i am working in that. Because it is giving same Invalid captcha response as when i check on [link](example.in) with deliberately entering wrong captcha. @devpro

Comment: Google ReCaptcha ??

Comment: no its is different captcha... if you know the trick than can help me @devpro

Comment: which captcha are u using here? and what error are u getting? i suggest u to create another question for getting more exposure

Comment: actually (example.in) whom i am making request uses captcha, i wants that captcha. I am using (example.in)'s captcha link just for a test purpose. But its captcha link keeps on changing as per live time. So i am getting wrong captcha response. Getting error *Invalid captcha